# Django User Model, which one should I use, AbstractBaseUser or AbstractUser model?

Tags: django, model

I honestly do not know the difference between the two, `AbstractBaseUser` and `AbstractUser` model class.

So, in my project, a website for a school, I might need the student number to be the username and I need to add more fields than just the existing fields in the default `AUTH_USER_MODEL` of django. I think I really need to substitute the user model (or, do I?) but what I do not know is how should I configure my custom model, should I use `AbstractBaseUser` or `AbstractUser`?

Thanks!

Comment: so if you want to keep django default fields and add your custom fields to them use AbstractUser.

Answer (score 2):

I'll explain regaring the AbstractUser & AbstractBaseUser

You can choose the model according to your requirement

AbstractBaseUser provides the core implementation of a user model, including hashed passwords and tokenized password resets.

```
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), blank=True, null=True)

    is_active = True

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    # Stores the raw password if set_password() is called so that it can
    # be passed to password_changed() after the model is saved.
    _password = None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_username()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._password is not None:
            password_validation.password_changed(self._password, self)
            self._password = None

    def get_username(self):
        """Return the username for this User."""
        return getattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD)

    def clean(self):
        setattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD, self.normalize_username(self.get_username()))

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.get_username(),)

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        """
        Always return False. This is a way of comparing User objects to
        anonymous users.
        """
        return False

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        """
        Always return True. This is a way to tell if the user has been
        authenticated in templates.
        """
        return True

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)
        self._password = raw_password

    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        """
        Return a boolean of whether the raw_password was correct. Handles
        hashing formats behind the scenes.
        """
        def setter(raw_password):
            self.set_password(raw_password)
            # Password hash upgrades shouldn't be considered password changes.
            self._password = None
            self.save(update_fields=["password"])
        return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)

    def set_unusable_password(self):
        # Set a value that will never be a valid hash
        self.password = make_password(None)

    def has_usable_password(self):
        """
        Return False if set_unusable_password() has been called for this user.
        """
        return is_password_usable(self.password)

    def get_session_auth_hash(self):
        """
        Return an HMAC of the password field.
        """
        key_salt = "django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.get_session_auth_hash"
        return salted_hmac(key_salt, self.password).hexdigest()

    @classmethod
    def get_email_field_name(cls):
        try:
            return cls.EMAIL_FIELD
        except AttributeError:
            return 'email'

    @classmethod
    def normalize_username(cls, username):
        return unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', username) if isinstance(username, str) else username
```

The AbstractUser is inherited from AbstractBaseUser.... So it having all the properties of AbstractBaseUser and it having it's own properties

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        abstract = True

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Return the short name for the user."""
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """Send an email to this user."""
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```